# GetDrives gives only local drives in Windows Service

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have created a Windows Service that runs under a domain user that has (administrator) rights to all network sources.

At the start of the Windows Service I have included the following code:

```
My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser()
```

If I use IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives to get a collection of all drives, then the result is only a collection of local drives, not network drives (drive mappings).

What am I missing here?

NB: Although I use VB.NET I understand/know also C#, so that's why I tagged this question also with C#. So C# example are also welcome.

Comment: My is only in VB.Net, it is not available in C#.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to depend on at what point those drives are mapped.  For example, it is possible that your drive mappings are set up via a login script that is not being run.

If this is the case, you can either reference the drives via UNC path, or map them yourself first, this kind of thing:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MapDriveLetter.aspx

Comment: Additionally, it is going to depend on the user that runs the services vs. has established the drive mappings.

Comment: I don´t want to map them myself, but just getting the available mapping for the user under which the Windows Service is run.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                foreach (DriveInfo di in drives)
                {
                    if (di.IsReady)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Volume label: {0} ", di.VolumeLabel);
                        Console.WriteLine("Drive Type: {0} ", di.DriveType);
                        Console.WriteLine("Free space: {0} bytes ", di.TotalFreeSpace);
                        Console.WriteLine("Drive Size: {0} bytes \n", di.TotalSize);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle ex
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have just tried this and it gets all the drives including network.   Hope it helps.

Comment: I´m using an procedure just like yours. It works while running in a commandline but not in a Windows Service.

Comment: Sorry Mike my mistake.  Does this have to be a windows service?  You will run into a few problems with it being a service.  First if not user is logged in then there is nothing to report but the main problem is that the service would need to run under the current users credential, I am not aware of anyway to do that. If a scheduled task is an option it would certainly be an easier route to take although I am not sure if it is the best or most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a misunderstanding. as noted in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172994%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), `My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser()` only sets current thread's principals. Your thread only impersonates user. It DOES NOT connect to the user session where network mappings are stored.

To access mapped drives of a user you need to access currently logged on user's desktop session which is meaningless since there may be no user logged on.

To make fun, I had one written a windows service which spans an executable in logged on user's windows session as user launched it, and connect to the outlook and send mail to whole company "Hey, desserts for everybody, my treat!".

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: How do I connect to the user session; do you have an example?

Comment: I had to leave all code, so I do not currently any code but following link may help you: http://developex.com/custom-software/devxexec.html look for "How to run an application for a user from the Windows service" section